# Django CMS Plugin: Can't see model fields in interface

Tags: python, django, django-cms

This is my first attempt making Django CMS plugin. I have following files ready:

**cms_plugins.py**

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from cms.models import CMSPlugin

from . import models


class SurveyPluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    """Show Polls entered by Admin."""

    cache = False
    # model = models.QuickAidPluginModel
    module = "Survey"
    name = "Awesome Survey v1.0"
    render_template = 'survey/_hello.html'

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        return context


plugin_pool.register_plugin(SurveyPluginPublisher)
```

**models.py**

```
# encoding: utf-8
from cms.models import CMSPlugin, python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from cms.models import CMSPlugin


class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.name)

    def questions(self):
        if self.pk:
            return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
        else:
            return None

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class SurveyPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    name = models.CharField("Survey Name", max_length=255, default='Survey Name',
                            help_text='Enter Survey Name')
    description = models.CharField("Survey Description", max_length=500, blank=True, help_text='Write Description here')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Returning some Survey Text"
```

**template file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hi Survey</h2>
</body>
</html
```

But when I got Edit Page option and try to add Plugin it shows this screen

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest it's because you've defined `module` and not `model` on your plugin class, therefore it doesn't know what fields you've got. Here's an example of a plugin class; https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/blob/master/djangocms_link/cms_plugins.py

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a form:

forms.py:

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        field = ['name', 'description']
```

models.py:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from cms.models import CMSPlugin, python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from cms.models import CMSPlugin


class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.name)

    def questions(self):
        if self.pk:
            return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
        else:
            return None

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class SurveyPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    name = models.CharField("Survey Name", max_length=255, default='Survey Name',
                        help_text='Enter Survey Name')
    description = models.CharField("Survey Description", max_length=500, blank=True, help_text='Write Description here')
    form = SurveyForm

    def __str__(self):
        return "Returning some Survey Text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line `model = models.SurveyPluginModel` to your `SurveyPluginPublisher`. It needs to know about its models.

Also, I'd suggest to add `fieldsets` as an attribute. It allows to design the admin interface. It is not necessary, however.